# Firestore queries in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-provider

I'm finding it really hard to understand the syntax for queries for cloud_firestore in flutter.
I've not been able to make a single query for the past while and all my efforts to understand it are failing since there are different in many tutorials. 
 Is there any way anyone can help me with a simplified example for CRUD operations in firestore ?, especially with provider would be of more help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically all the CRUD operations in firestore will be asynchronous. So you should have minimum knowledge in **async** and **await**. Initialise firestore with the firebase_credential.json file. And call the methods for the **CRUD** operations.

[CRUD operation in flutter using firestore](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-firebase-realtime-database-crud-operations-using-provider-c242a01f6a10)

Comment: I went through this medium article, it is very clear, but I had another doubt pop up there, the article uses get_it as a  dependency injection, but what if  I wanted to use only Provider since ProxyProvider is available in 3.0.0. i got to know about this through FilledStacks youtube videos. So I was confused more as to what to use.